# pinescript for not yet closed candle, not yet closed candle should be invisib

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, technical-indicator, candlesticks

Can you please share the pinescript for tradingview which should hide the current moving candle, I mean the not yet closed candle should be invisible, once closed it should be visible

```
//@version=4
//Paints an unconfirmed candle gray to remind the trader that the bar can look different by close and reduce mistakes.

study("!", overlay=true)

rt = barstate.isconfirmed

barcolor(rt ? na : color.white, title="Unconfirmed candle")
```

I tried the above code but it still showing the wick color, i want the whole candle to be invisible.
kindly help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but there is no function that you can use to color a wick, but you can create your own candlestick chart.

```
//@version=5

New_Color = not barstate.isconfirmed ? color.new(color.gray, 0) : close >= 
open ? color.green : color.red
plotcandle(open, high, low, close, 'New Candles', New_Color, New_Color, 
bordercolor = New_Color)
```

If you want to use a chart with Renko or Line Break, use a security function for the plotcandle function.

Comment: thanks a lot, your code helped me, i modified like this:

//@version=4
//Paints an unconfirmed candle gray to remind the trader that the bar can look different by close and reduce mistakes.

study("!!", overlay=true)

con = barstate.isconfirmed ? (close >=open ? color.green : color.red) : color.new(color.gray, 0)
plotcandle(open, high, low, close, 'New Candles', con, con , bordercolor = con)